# Infinite sum over Gamma functions?

Tags: summation, closed-form, gamma-function

I am having quite a bit of trouble understanding  this sum.
Can someone explain to me exactly how to this from 1 to 3,very easily way?

[Question its from this webpage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217102/closed-form-for-an-infinite-sum-over-gamma-functions)

Thanks.

[image: enter imageenter link description here description here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\color{red}{1}\mapsto \color{red}{2}$ is just a consequence of integration by parts. If $p(x)$ is a polynomial, a primitive of $p(x)\,e^{-x}$ is given by $\left[p(x)+p'(x)+p''(x)+\ldots\right]e^{-x}$. In our case we have $p(x)=\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$. $\color{red}{2}\mapsto \color{red}{3}$ comes from evaluating the given double series at $z=0$ and at $z=b$. In the first case (evaluation at $z=0$), just the contribute from $k=0$ might be different from zero.